# in actionscript, how to tell whether the type of a number if Number or int or uint?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript

```
var n:Number = 1;
trace("n is Number:" + (n is Number)); //true
trace("n is int:" + (n is int)); //true
trace("n is uint:" + (n is uint)); //true

var m:Number = 1;
trace("m is Number:" + (m is Number)); //true
trace("m is int:" + (m is int)); //true
trace("m is uint:" + (m is uint)); //true
```

They all true! in actionscript, how to tell whether the type of a number if Number or int or uint?

Comment: Why you have to know this? Why is the reason for this?

Comment: What is the context of this problem? Do you want to know if an number is real or natural? Or something else?

Comment: in As byteArray.read* and byteArray.write* methods are clear typed. It has writeDouble, writeInt, writeFloat....
I want to write a conventional buff writer, which receive input:* and will use the proper-typed writer methods to write the data segment in to a bytearray buff. That's why I need to tell Number, int, uint on the fly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The confusion here stems from a peculiar subtlety about how AS3 handles types and numbers. The `is` operator tests class inheritance, but `int` and `uint` are not actually classes. (That's why they don't get capitalized - because they have no class definition.) They're more like type associations, which if used properly can gain you certain conveniences and performance improvements. But for inheritance purposes, a Number is a Number is a Number.

What this means in practice is, if you make a variable that is typed as, say, `uint` then Flash will store that value internally in a 32-bit unsigned format (rather than the 64bit format used for `Number`). And if you change the value of that variable, it will remain in the same format, so the restrictions on `uint` will be enforced:

```
var a:uint = 0;
a--;
trace(a); // 4294967295 - it wrapped around
```

But it's really the *reference* to your number that is typed as `uint`, not the number itself. If you make a new untyped reference, this will be apparent:

```
var a:uint = 0;
var b:* = a;
b--
trace(b); // -1
```

So to return to your problem, how should you implement your buffer writer? Due to the inherent subtlety in how Flash treats these types I don't think there's an absolutely correct answer. One approach would be to use `uint` or `int` if the data meets the restrictions on those types, and use `Number` otherwise. This would save memory and it could preserve accuracy. But treating all numbers as `Number` also strikes me as a defensible approach. I think it depends on what you plan to do with the buffer.

Comment: Thank you for your response. ".. but int and uint are not actually classes..." this answers my confusion. My original idea is to write a simple mapping in ByteArray writers, and to auto-determine the type of data writer by the type of the input data. That's why I was looking for a way to tell Number, int and uint on the fly.

Comment: So there is no way to ask Flash for the type of this _reference_ either? If the variables are actually class properties, the VM knows what type they are, no?

Answer (score 2):

It's easy. I put additional variables to show how it works. Hope this helps.

```
var n:Number = 1;
var v:Number = 1.1;
var r:Number = -1;

trace(getQualifiedClassName (n));//output shows 'int'
trace(getQualifiedClassName (v));//output shows 'Number'
trace(getQualifiedClassName (r));//output shows 'int'
```

Comment: What he's asking for would expect all of those to return Number, since that's how the variables are typed.

Answer (score 0):

well, to test whether a number is an integer, you can try:

var epsilon:Number = 1E-6;
var n:Number;
if (Math.abs(n-int(n))

if a number is negative then it must be an int and cannot be an uint. However, if the number is negative and < -2 147 483 648 then it must be a Number and not an int or an uint. If it is positive and > 4 294 967 295 then it must be a Number too. If it is positive and between 2 147 483 648 and 4 294 967 295 it may be either an uint or a Number. If it is positive and < 2 147 483 648 it may be an int or an uint, or a Number.

Basically, what I'm trying to say is, there's no way to tell. why do you want to tell? what do you need this for? There probably are other solutions to your problem.