# Check if value is a number

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, adobe, air

How can i simply check if a returned value of type `int` or `uint` is a number?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Simple:

```
if(_myValue is Number)
{
    fire();

}// end if
```

**[UPDATE]**

Keep in mind that if `_myValue` is of type `int` or `uint`, then `(_myValue is Number)` will also equate to `true`. If you want to know if `_myValue` is a number that isn't an integer(int) or unsigned integer (uint), in other words a float, then you can simply modify the conditional as follows:

```
(_myValue is Number && !(_myValue is int) && !(_myValue is uint))
```

Let's look at an example:

```
package 
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.Event;

    public class Main extends Sprite 
    {

        public function Main():void 
        {
            if (stage) init();
            else addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
        }

        private function init(e:Event = null):void 
        {
            removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);

            var number1:Object = 1; // int
            var number2:Object = 1.1; // float
            var number3:Object = 0x000000; // uint

            trace(number1 is Number); // true
            trace(number2 is Number); // true
            trace(number3 is Number); // true

            trace(number1 is Number && !(number1 is int) && !(number1 is uint)); // false
            trace(number2 is Number && !(number2 is int) && !(number2 is uint)); // true
            trace(number3 is Number && !(number3 is int) && !(number3 is uint)); // false

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: "_myValue is Number" will still be true and typeof(_myValue) will still be "number" even if _myValue is typed as int or uint. According to http://stackoverflow.com/a/9447869/88409 Flash stores integer values as ints, and as Number only if there is a fractional part in the value or it exceeds 0x0FFFFFFF (highest value that can be stored in the remaining 28-bits of the 32-bit atom that reserves 3 bits for a type description and 1 bit for the sign).  See also http://stackoverflow.com/a/2697151/88409 and a test case here: http://troyworks.com/blog/2007/12/02/as3-understanding-uint-int-number/

Comment: Questioner wants to know if _myValue is a number, not a Number.

Comment: @Robert sorry I can be a bit of a dunce sometimes, not quite sure what you are getting at.

Comment: @Taurayi Your method returns false for valid numeric strings. The question is ambiguous but I assumed he was looking for a way to tell if something is a number, not just if it's of a numeric type.

Comment: To account for numeric strings as well as Number, int, and uint, the test is much simpler: `var isNumeric:Boolean = !isNaN(Number(value));`.  That will handle any Number value, but will also try to convert strings to numbers.  If it's a number or can be converted to a number, then it's a numeric value.  No need to test against Number, int, and uint types with the `is` operator explicitly.

Answer (score 5):

If you only want to know if myValue is one of the *numeric types* (Number, int, uint), you can check if `(_myValue is Number)` as Taurayi suggested.

If you *also* want to know if _myValue is a *numeric string* (like "6320" or "5.987"), use this:

```
if (!isNaN(Number(_myValue)))
{
    fire();
}
```

It uses `Number(_myValue)` to cast `_myValue` to the `Number` class. If `Number` is unable to convert it into a useful number it will return `NaN`, so we use `!isNaN()` to make sure the returned value is not "not a number".

It will return true for any variable of type `Number` (as long as its value isn't `NaN`), `int`, `uint`, and strings that contain a valid representation of a number.

Comment: IMO, this is the best answer.  It's exactly what I would have posted.  Although it doesn't completely explain the relationship between Number, int, and uint (i.e. any int is a Number, but Numbers aren't necessarily ints or uints), this implementation is better than the conditional checks, in part because it also takes numeric strings into account.

Comment: @Triynko I edited my answer to better explain about the numeric types.

Answer (score 4):

These methods could be problematic if you wish to check the input of a text field, which is 'always' a string. If you have a string with "123" and check with "123" is Number, you will get a false. So Number("123") would give true, but then again so will Number("lalala") (event though the result is NaN which will tell you NaN is Number (true).

To work with string you could do:

```
var s:String = "1234";
String(Number(s)) == String(s);
--True

var s:String = "lalala";
String(Number(s)) == String(s);
--False
```

Answer (score 3):

There are

- [isNaN](http://www.adobe.com/support/flash/action_scripts/actionscript_dictionary/actionscript_dictionary392.html) (You will want to negate this)
- [typeof](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/operators.html#typeof) (Not sure how strongly type Number works)
- and [is](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5026786/as3-check-if-value-is-a-number/5026890#5026890) (which was already mentioned, again I am not sure how strong, types hold)