# In Actionscript 3, why is the dynamic type of large int values Number?

Tags: actionscript-3, int

I have noticed that if I create an int with a large value, the dynamic type of the object seems to be Number.

Example:

```
var int1:int = 0x8000000;
var type1:String = flash.utils.getQualifiedClassName(int1); // Returns "int"

var int2:int = 0x10000000;
var type2:String = flash.utils.getQualifiedClassName(int2); // Returns "Number"
```

What is going on here? Both of the values are well below the [maximum value of an int](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/int.html), which is 2,147,483,647 (2^31-1).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

What's going on is that the AS3 virtual machine uses 32 bit "atoms" to store the values of primitive types.

3 of those 32 bits are used for describing the type, meaning there are 29 bits left.

Since `int` is a signed type - using 1 bit for the sign - that leaves 28 bits for a positive integer. Making the highest number you can write in the remaining 28 bits:

```
0x0FFFFFFF = 268435455
```

As soon as the integer needs more than 29 bits, the atom is changed by the VM into a `Number` type (which is really represented as a 29 bit pointer to the actual 64 bit double precision float).

So, the value defined as "maximum value of an int" doesn't really make all that much sense (since `Number` can store integral values up to 53 bits, but `int` will limit it to 32) - other than in terms of:

- communicating with other languages/technologies (which mostly use 32 bits for their integers)
- making the results (mostly) predictable to programmers used to 32 bit integers; and
- future-proofing (in case the internal representation changes in the future).

As a sidenote, there are quite a few peculiarities with ints and Numbers - including that this:

```
var i:Number = 2.0;
```

... is stored as int until the decimals are actually needed.