# In as3 is there a way to check Textinput isnt number?

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript

I need to check if the text input contains anything that isnt int(number), wondering if it is possible.

```
if (!isNaN(s1.range))) {
        s1.tet.text = "Please enter fields that only contains number";
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5026786/as3-check-if-value-is-a-number

Comment: I tried putting (s1.rangelow !== [Number])) but it gives me an error comparison between a value static type to an possibly unrelated type Array

Comment: That's not the syntax. (!(s1.rangelow is Number))

Comment: I tried that too, that won't let anything thru, even the input are numbers i also tried (!(s1.rangelow is int))

Comment: I read that in this thread it might not be possible? http://www.actionscript.org/forums/showthread.php3?t=211012

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to check a text (String) to contain non digits, I would personally use RegExp.
It would be easier for you to test the string against a regular expression.

Here's a simple example that will check for anything that is not a digit

```
var str:String = "04.sdf..";
var re:RegExp = /[\D]/g;
trace(str.match(re).length); // 6
```

In this example there are 6 char's that are not digits, therefor we can show an error to the user.

Here's a good tutorial on RegExp if you believe it can be helpful to you:

http://coursesweb.net/actionscript/regexp-regular-expressions-actionscript

Comment: An aside - you can restrict what characters can be entered in a TextField using the "restrict" property. Docs here:
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS8d7bb3e8da6fb92f-20050207122bd5f80cb-7ff6.html